# In C# how to get return value from stored procedure using ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have the following query:

```
create proc [dbo].[DeleteParts] 
    @TransNo nvarchar (6), @fpart nvarchar(25) 
AS 
    DECLARE @Returns BIT 
    SET @Returns = 1 

    BEGIN 
       TRY  
          BEGIN TRANSACTION 

          DELETE FROM PARTABLE 
          WHERE TransNo = @TransNo and fpart = @fpart

          COMMIT 
       END TRY 
       BEGIN CATCH   
           Print 'Delete failed'    
           SET @Returns = 0      
           -- Any Error Occurred during Transaction. Rollback     
           IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0       
               ROLLBACK  -- Roll back 
       END CATCH

       RETURN @Returns
```

This compiles perfectly fine.

In C#, I want to execute this query and get the return value.

My code is as below:

```
using(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand deletecommand = this._connection.CreateCommand())
{
   deletecommand.CommandText = "DeleteParts";
   deletecommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   deletecommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransNo", ItemSODBOM.SONO);
   deletecommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fpart", ItemSODBOM.fbompart);

   string ReturnValue = deletecommand.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
}
```

It does not give me any error but instead it is returning number of rows affected, I want to return 1 or 0.

Example: if delete operation success then return 1 and if it fails then return 0.

Any help with source code would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Pradeep

Comment: As RemoteSojourner notes; you *aren't* returning anything

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! (and **don't** use the "quoting" mechanism instead - that just messes up your code!!)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need a parameter with `Direction` set to `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`

Something like:

```
SqlParameter returnParameter = deleteCommand.Parameters.Add("RetVal", SqlDbType.Int);
returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
...
deleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
...
int returnValue = (int) returnParameter.Value;
```

You Stored Procedure needs to return this return value of course:

```
create proc [dbo].[DeleteParts]      
    @TransNo nvarchar (6),   
    @fpart nvarchar(25)  
AS      
DECLARE @Returns BIT      
SET @Returns = 1     
...
RETURN @Returns
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see that you are returning the value. Please add  the Return statement to return any value from the stored proc.

Comment: it was missed from that proc, now it is added

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the `@@ROWCOUNT` which you cannot set. So really you cannot use it to return values.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the result is returned as a row, like a normal select query would be. You can get at it using a reader or adaptor.

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteNonQuery` will return the number of rows affected but NOT data (that's why its a non-query). So it won't bring anything back.

This might be useful to read:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/76434-executenonquery-with-output-parameters/

You'll need to use a different mechanism to get your data out - how about *ExecuteReader* with  an output parameter?

Comment: Link now goes to online gambling site

Answer (score 0):

you must specify output type in stored procedures like this

```
@IDout                  [int] output
```

then add this parameter

```
SPParamReturnCollection sp = new SPParamReturnCollection();
        sp.Add(new SPParams { Name = "IDout", ParamDirection = ParameterDirection.Output, Type = SqlDbType.Int });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT TransNo FROM [PARTABLE] WHERE TransNo = @TransNo and fpart = @fpart
        BEGIN                       
            DELETE FROM PARTABLE 
                        WHERE TransNo = @TransNo and fpart = @fpart

            SELECT @TransNo AS RETURNVAL
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
             SELECT 0 AS RETURNVAL
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

Naming a variable "@Returns" doesn't magically return it's value, you have to actually return the value.

You can't return a bit value, the return value is always an integer. If you want to sent a bit value back, you would have to use an output parameter instead.

Add a `return` statement to the procedure:

```
create proc [dbo].[DeleteParts] 
  @TransNo nvarchar (6), @fpart nvarchar(25) 
AS 
  DECLARE @Returns INT
  SET @Returns = 1 

  BEGIN 
    TRY  
      BEGIN TRANSACTION 

      DELETE FROM PARTABLE 
      WHERE TransNo = @TransNo and fpart = @fpart

      COMMIT 
    END TRY 
    BEGIN CATCH   
       Print 'Delete failed'    
       SET @Returns = 0      
       -- Any Error Occurred during Transaction. Rollback     
       IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0       
           ROLLBACK
    END CATCH

RETURN @Returns
```

Add a parameter with the direction `ReturnValue` to receive the return value:

```
int returnValue;
using(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand deletecommand = this._connection.CreateCommand())
{
   deletecommand.CommandText = "DeleteParts";
   deletecommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   deletecommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransNo", ItemSODBOM.SONO);
   deletecommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fpart", ItemSODBOM.fbompart);
   var returnParameter = deletecommand.Parameters.Add("@ret", SqlDbType.Int);
   returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

   deletecommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   returnValue = (int)returnParameter.Value;
}
```

Comment: Nothing is different from Joe's post

Comment: @Pradeep: Yes, everything in Joe's post is also in this post, but that doesn't mean that everything in this post is in Joe's post.