# Entity Framework swallows SQL Server exception / error (but ADO.NET does not)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, ado.net

**Problem:**

I have a stored procedure and I am able execute it successfully with both EF and ADO.NET with no issues. However, if the stored procedure throws an error (using `RAISERROR` or `THROW`), only ADO.NET catches it and not EF. EF simply swallows the exception instead of catching it. I am using EF code first (not designer).

**Description:**

I have a basic stored procedure (looks big because of boiler plate code) as follows (chopped off / hand-written):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SampleProc
    (@id BIGINT)
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        IF EXISTS (SELECT Id    
                   FROM SampleTable
                   WHERE Id = @id)
        BEGIN
            --;THROW 50000, 'row not found', 1
            RAISERROR ('row not found', -- Message text.  
                16, -- Severity.  
                1 -- State.  
            ); 
        END

        BEGIN TRANSACTION   
            DELETE FROM SampleTable
            WHERE Id  = @id
        COMMIT TRANSACTION

        SELECT 1 AS ReturnValue, CAST(@id AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [Message]
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT,
                @ErrorNumber   INT,
                @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000),
                @ErrorState INT,
                @ErrorLine  INT,
                @ErrorProc NVARCHAR(200)

        SET @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
        SET @ErrorNumber   = ERROR_NUMBER()
        SET @ErrorMessage  = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        SET @ErrorState    = ERROR_STATE()
        SET @ErrorLine     = ERROR_LINE()
        SET @ErrorProc     = ERROR_PROCEDURE()
        SET @ErrorMessage  = 'Problem deleting from SampleTable.' + CHAR(13) + 'SQL Server Error Message: ' + CAST(@ErrorNumber AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' in procedure: ' + @ErrorProc + ' Line: ' + CAST(@ErrorLine AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Error text: ' + @ErrorMessage
    
        IF @ErrorState  = 0
            SET @ErrorState = 1
    
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END
        --;THROW 50000, @ErrorMessage, 1
        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage , @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState, @ErrorNumber)
    END CATCH
END
```

I execute the same using ADO.NET as follows (works with no issues and catches the `RAISERROR/THROW` from this stored procedure):

```
    var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringKey); //ADO.NET Connection

    try
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SampleProc", connection))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("id", id));                    

            if (connection != null && connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connection.Open();
            }

            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (rdr.Read())
                {
                    result.ReturnValue = (int)rdr["ReturnValue"];
                    result.Message = rdr["Message"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.Warn($"WARNING: nothing is returned from SampleProc.");
                }
            }
        }                

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error("ERROR:", ex);
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection != null && connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, replacing just the ADO.NET connection (in above code) with EF connection makes the exception swallowed (does not catch the `RAISERROR` of the stored procedure):

```
var connection = (SqlConnection)Database.Connection; //EF connection - rest of code stays same
```

Tried using the following two ways as well (using EF), but with no luck:

```
    Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
            "exec SampleProc @Id",
            new SqlParameter("Id", id));
    
    result = Database.SqlQuery<StoredProcedureGenericResult>(
            "exec SampleProc @Id",
            new SqlParameter("Id", id))
        .First();
```

Anyone faced similar issue?

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using `RAISERROR` and not `THROW`?

Comment: tried THROW as well...same experience

Comment: That doesn't really answer why you're using the old method though. Even the  [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) suggest you should use `THROW`, so I just wanted to understand why.

Comment: My bad.  We had been migrating from old sql to new sql.  Yes, we can change RAISERROR to THROW with no issues at all.  I understand it is recommended and we don't have any problems doing that.  Before posting here, I played with both RAISERROR and THROW and still ended up with the same problem.

Comment: Is error occurring on SQL Server during executing stored procedure?

Comment: @Lamu, I updated my code on how I tested using THROW

Comment: @jdweng, yes.  It does raise error with wrong id (when testing SP directly in SSMS).  It raises the error and ADO.NET catches it successfully, but not EF.

Comment: @user203687 you have now THROW and RAISERROR. Is that intentional?

Comment: just corrected the mistake...the code was hand-crafted for this post (removing the unnecessary code)...but, it happens with either THROW or RAISERROR...Of course, would not use both ;)

Comment: The only way to get c# to know an error occurs is to return an output parameter (Success, Fail) and when exception occurs in stored procedure return Fail.  Then in c# you can test the output parameter.

Comment: @jdweng *why* use an `OUTPUT` parameter, when `RETURN` is designed exactly to denote the success of a Stored Procedure. `0` means success, anything else failure.

Comment: Aside: You could simply execute the `delete` and then if `@@RowCount = 0` you have your _row not found_ condition. It also takes care of the bug you introduced by checking for the existence of the row _outside_ the transaction, then wrapping a single statement in a transaction. That allows another process to delete the row between the `exists` check and the `delete`.

Comment: @Larnu : ExecuteNonQuery returns an integer which is usually the number of rows affected.  So zero means no rows changed which is different from an exception.

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` still populates the return value, @jdweng. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#remarks): *"Although the ExecuteNonQuery returns no rows, any output parameters or return values mapped to parameters are populated with data."* As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5016047/2029983) demonstrates.

Comment: Probably better to return -1 on exception.